# Interrupt processing of current item if new items arrive

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have the following piece of code:

```
        Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangingEventArgs>(_parent, "PropertyChanged")
            .Subscribe(ep => 
            {
                switch (ep.EventArgs.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "ValorBlurMenor":
                        LoadBlurMenor();
                        break;
                    case "ValorBlurMaior":
                        LoadBlurMaior();
                        break;
                }
            });
```

My problem is that `ValorBlurMenor` and `ValorBlurMaior` are changed via WPF sliders, and `LoadBlurMaior()` and `LoadBlurMenor()` take some time to evaluate.

I'm looking for a way to interrupt/cancel the execution of the `Subscribe` delegate for an item if new item(s) arrive, thus always performing the processing only on the last item.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "`LoadBlurMaior()` and `LoadBlurMenor()` take some time to evaluate"? Rx will always wait until the previous subscription delegate is finished before processing the next value. So unless you mean that `LoadBlurMaior()` and `LoadBlurMenor()` trigger some sort of asynchronous behaviour then your code should be already doing what you ask.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for your interest. When I change a property in this viewmodel, via UI Slider, I start to trigger some changes that are performed by `LoadBlur**()` methods. But if, before that processing ends, I end up changing the value again in the slider, I don't want to wait for the previous processing to complete. Instead I want to process the latest data right away, discarding partial progress from former data. I guess this is more or less what `Observable.Switch` does.

Comment: What "partial progress from former data" is there? Rx doesn't ever have partial progress. Is it the UI that has the partial progress? If so, then this is a WPF question and nothing to do with Rx.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry if I was not clear. Let's suppose a friend gives me an orange and asks me peel it. I start to peel the orange, but before I can finish, he gets _another_ one. What I mean with "partial progress from former data" is the partially peeled orange that I no longer have use for (not the best example, but anyway). My goal is to always start peeling the newest orange right away, and preferrably stop peeling older ones as soon as a new one arrive. This is not unlike the "live search" example.

Comment: So Rx would go like this: Suppose a friend (observable) gives me an orange (value) and asks me to peel it (observer), then my friend will patiently wait until I finishing peeling my first orange before even telling me there is another one (if there is one).

Comment: To get more complex behaviour you need to change from `IObservable<T>` to `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` using `Select`/`Switch` or `SelectMany` to get the kind of behaviour that you want. Uwy has pretty much nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get it to work is to use `Observable.FromAsync<>` overload that uses the `CancellationToken` and use the token in your code to frequently check for cancellation :

```cs
public class PlainNotifiable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool takeFiveSeconds;
    private bool takeTenSeconds;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool TakeFiveSeconds
    {
        get => this.takeFiveSeconds;
        set
        {
            this.takeFiveSeconds = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.TakeFiveSeconds)));
        }
    }
    public bool TakeTenSeconds
    {
        get => this.takeTenSeconds;
        set
        {
            this.takeTenSeconds = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.TakeTenSeconds)));
        }
    }

    public async Task TakeSomeTime(int seconds, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Started waiting {0} seconds", seconds);
        await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000, token);
        Trace.TraceInformation("Stoped waiting {0} seconds", seconds);

    }
}
public static async void Test()
{
    var test = new PlainNotifiable();
    async Task<Unit> propertyNameToLongTask(EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs> args, CancellationToken token)
    {
        switch (args.EventArgs.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(test.TakeFiveSeconds):
                await test.TakeSomeTime(5, token);
                break;

            case nameof(test.TakeTenSeconds):
                await test.TakeSomeTime(10, token);
                break;
        }
        return Unit.Default;

    }

    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(test, nameof(test.PropertyChanged))
        .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(token => propertyNameToLongTask(x, token)))
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(x => Trace.TraceInformation("Beep boop"));

    Trace.TraceInformation("Started sending notifications");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    test.TakeTenSeconds = true;
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    test.TakeFiveSeconds = true;
    Trace.TraceInformation("Finished sending notifications");

}
```

It gives the following output:

```
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Started sending notifications
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Started waiting 10 seconds
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Started waiting 5 seconds
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Finished sending notifications
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Stoped waiting 5 seconds
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Beep boop
```

Key points are :

- `Observable.FromAsync()`: Create an observable with a correct `CancellationToken` support
- `Switch()`: Flatenize by only subscribing to the latest observable, it also property dispose the previous observable using, in this case, the `CancellationToken`